# For $W=\cup_{U\in\mathcal U} U$ show that there exists $U_1,\dots,U_n: \ \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(U_i) > \frac{1 - \epsilon}{3^d}\lambda(W)$

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis, lebesgue-measure, convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I'm trying to solve the following, which is Exercise 13.15 in the book Probability Theory by A. Klenke.

*Let $C \subset \mathbb R^d $ be an open, bounded and convex set and assume that
$$
\mathcal{U} \subset \left \{ x+rC: x \in \mathbb R^d, r>0 \right \}
$$
is such that
$$
W:= \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{U}}U 
$$
has finite Lebesgue measure $\lambda(W)$. Show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists finitely many pairwise disjoint sets $U_1, \dots, U_n$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda(U_i) > \frac{1 - \epsilon}{3^d}\lambda(W). \tag 1
$$
Show by a counterexample that the condition of similarity of the open sets in $\mathcal{U} $ is essential.*

---

This is my approach: Given that the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ is inner regular, pick a compact set $K \subset W$ such that
$$
\lambda(W) - \epsilon < \lambda(K).
$$
Since the open sets\footnote{We take it as given that $C$ is open implies that $x + rC$ is open.} in $\mathcal{U}$ covers $K$ and $K$ is compact there exists a finite number $m$ of them such that $U_i, \dots, U_m$ covers $K$. Order the $U_i$:s such that, if
$$
U_i = x_i + r_iC, \qquad i=1, \dots m
$$
then $r_1 \ge r_1 \ge \dots \ge r_m$.

Now, I have seen a similar Lemma in Rudin's Real and complex analysis (Lemma 7.3) where the sets $U_i$ are open balls $U_i = B(x_i,r_i)$. In that case one may do as follows: to get a disjoint collection of sets we let $i_1=1$, and then we discard every $U_j$ that intersects $U_{i_1}$. Let $U_{i_2}$ be the first remaining $U_j$ (if any exists) and discard the remaining $U_j$ that intersects $U_{i_2}$. Continuing this process gives a a collection of $n$ disjoint sets. Then one may claim that,
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^m x_i+ r_iC \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n x_{i_k} + 3r_{i_k}C.
$$
The conclusion then follows (for that Lemma) from
$$
\lambda \left(B(x, 3r)\right) =3^d \lambda \left(B(x, r)\right) 
$$
and subadditivity.

> I don't think the exact same argument works here but is there a similar approach to get at least pairwise disjoint sets in the case of this exercise? And further such that (1) holds?

> Secondly, what is the meaning of the last sentence in the exercise, "Show by a counterexample that the condition of similarity of the open sets in $\mathcal{U} $ is essential."?

Much grateful for any help provided!

Comment: I don't think that Rudin's trick will work, because it is based on the fact that balls are balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't think the exact same argument works here but is there a similar approach to get at least pairwise disjoint sets in the case of this exercise? And further such that (1) holds?

The proposed  argument is used to prove the [Vitali covering lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma).
As Martin Argerami [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720611/for-w-cup-u-in-mathcal-u-u-show-that-there-exists-u-1-dots-u-n-sum-i#comment7648551_3720611), it needs that $C=x-C$ for some $x\in\Bbb R^d$. Then we can replace it by a set $C’=C-x/2=-C'$ containing the origin of $\Bbb R^d$ and either (provided $C’$ is non-empty) construct [Minkowski functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) to endow $\Bbb R^d$ with the metric allowing to apply Vitali covering lemma for a metric space or directly providing the required claim:  if $$x_i+r_iC’\cap x_j+r_jC’\ne\varnothing$$ and $r_i\ge r_j$ then  $ x_j+r_jC’ \subset x_i+3r_iC'$. Indeed, let $$x\in x_i+r_iC’\cap x_j+r_jC’$$ be an arbitrary point and $y\in x_j+r_jC’$. Then $$y\in x_j + r_jC' \subset x-r_jC’+ r_jC’\subset x_i+r_iC’-r_jC’+ r_jC’\subset x_i+3r_iC’.$$

But the condition $C=x-C$ was missed and the argument doesn’t work now.

Moreover, the exercise claim is wrong as the following example shows.  Indeed, consider a simplex

$$C=C_d=\{(x_1,\dots,x_d):  x_i>0\mbox{ for each }i\mbox{ and } x_1+\dots+x_d<1\}.$$

We have $\lambda(C_d)=\frac 1{d!}$. Let $\mathcal U=\{x+C: x\in -C\}$. Then $W=\bigcup U=C-C$. Since each member of $\mathcal U$ contains the origin of $\Bbb R^d$, $\mathcal U$ has no disjoint subsets.

Let’s calculate $\lambda(W)$. For each $\delta=(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_d)\in \{-1,1\}^d$ put

$$W_\delta=\{(x_1,\dots, x_d)\in W: \forall i (\delta_ix_i>0) \}.$$

Let $\delta_+=\{1\le i\le d: \delta_i=1\}$, $\delta_-=\{1\le i\le d: \delta_i=1\}$, and $\pi_+$ and $\pi_-$ be the projections of the product $\Bbb R^n=\Bbb R^{\delta_+}\times \Bbb R^{\delta_-}$ into its factors $\Bbb R^{\delta_+}$ and $\Bbb R^{\delta_-}$, respectively. Put $k=|\delta_+|$. It is easy to see that if $1\le k\le d-1$ then $\pi_+(W_\delta)$ is a natural copy of $C_k$,  $\pi_-(W_\delta)$ is a natural copy of $C_{d-k}$, and $W_\delta=\pi_+(W_\delta)\times \pi_-( W_\delta)$. Thus $\lambda(W_\delta)=\frac 1{k!} \tfrac 1{(d-k)!}$.

So we have $$\lambda(W)=\sum\{\lambda(W_\delta): \delta\in \{-1,1\}^d \} =$$
$$\sum\left\{\frac 1{k!} \frac 1{(d-k)!}: \delta\in \{-1,1\}^d \mbox{ and } |\delta_+|=k\right\}=$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^d \frac 1{k!} \frac 1{(d-k)!}\cdot |\{\delta\in \{-1,1\}^d \mbox{ and } |\delta_+|=k\}|=$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^d\frac 1{k!} \frac 1{(d-k)!}{d\choose k}=\frac 1{d!}\sum_{k=0}^d {d\choose k}^2=\frac 1{d!} {2d\choose d}=\lambda(C){2d\choose d}$$
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients)) for the last equality.

Finally, [Robbins’ bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates) imply that

$$\frac {4^{d}}{\sqrt{\pi d}}\exp\left(-\frac {1}{8d-1}\right)<{2d\choose d}<\frac {4^{d}}{\sqrt{\pi d}}\exp\left(-\frac {1}{8d+1}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you! I believe I spotted two minor errors and corrected them in your anser.

Comment: Secondly, a silly thing, but I got stuck in showing $x_i + r_iC' - r_iC' + r_iC' \subset x_i + 3r_i C'$. How would go about showing this?

Comment: @MrFranzén Thanks for your correctections and sorry for the misprints. The inclusion holds because $C’$ is convex and $C’=-C$ (I added this to my answer).

Comment: Do you mean balanced? I know that for a balanced set $A$, $-A = A$. Or do you mean that since $C = x - C $ and $C $ is convex it follows that $-C' = C'$. I tried to prove this but couldn't...

Comment: @MrFranzén I tried to avoid a term “balanced” because it can have different definitions. Right, if $C=x-C$ then 
$$C’=C-x/2=(x-C)-x/2=x/2-C=-C’.$$

Comment: Got it! Thank you! One last question: given that $x_j + r_jC' \subset x_i +3r_jC'$ is it then meant that we should conclude from this that $x_j +r_C \subset x_i +3r_iC$?

Comment: @MrFranzén We deal at a level of $\mathcal U$. Since $C'=C-x$, $\mathcal U\subset \{y+rC':y\in\Bbb R^d, r>0\}$. Since $C'=-C'$, the proposed arguments allow to find a required subfamily of $\mathcal U$.

Comment: Right! Since every set of the form $y+rC$ may be written in the form $y'+r'C'$ we may simply assume that $\mathcal U = \{y + rC': y \in \mathbb R^d, r>0 \}$. Thanks again!

Comment: @MrFranzén I fixed a constant in the approximation of ${2d\choose d}$. Sorry for the error.

Comment: @AlexRavsky This is a great counterexample showing that the $C = x-C$ condition is required in general, but after calculating $\lambda(W)$ and $\lambda(U)$ for a few different $d$, it seems that this only violates the statement of the result for $d \geq 5$. Is there a similarly simple way to show that the "affine symmetry" condition $C = x-C$ is required for $d \in \{2,3,4\}$?

Answer (score 0):

For your last question regarding the statement:

> Show by a counterexample that the condition of similarity of the open sets in $\mathcal U$ is essential.

This means (as I understand it) that if $\mathcal U$ simply is a collection of convex open sets, and not necessarily sets of the form $x + rC$ for a *fixed* convex open set $C$, then this result fails.

Here is one counterexample in $\mathbb R^2$. Let $q \in (0,1)$, and let $\tilde C_0$ be the sector given in polar coordinates by $\{(r,\theta) : 0 < r < 1, \, 0 < \theta < 2\pi q\}$. Let $A_\theta : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ denote a rotation by $\theta$, let $\alpha > 0$, let $a = -\alpha(\cos\pi q, \sin\pi q) \in \mathbb R^2$, and let $C_\theta = A_\theta\left(a+\tilde C_0\right)$. Then each $C_\theta$ is an open sector with radius $1$ and angle $2\pi q$ containing the origin. If $\mathcal U = \left\{ C_\theta : 0 \leq \theta <2\pi\right\}$, $W = \bigcup_{\theta \in [0,2\pi)} C_\theta$, then we find that $W$ is the open disc of radius $1-\alpha$ centered at the origin. So $\lambda^2(W) = \pi(1-\alpha)^2$, and $\lambda^2(C_\theta) = \pi q$ for every $\theta$. Since no two sets in $\mathcal U$ are disjoint, the statement of the result implies:
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 : \quad \pi q = \lambda^2(C_\theta) > \frac{1-\epsilon}{9}\lambda^2(W) = \frac{1-\epsilon}9 \pi(1-\alpha)^2.
$$
Since this must hold for every $\epsilon > 0$, this means in particular that $q \geq \frac 1 9 (1-\alpha)^2$. This is false given appropriate choices of $q$ and $\alpha$, e.g. if $q \in (0,\frac 1 9)$ and if $\alpha < 1-3\sqrt q$.